# Script not working when evoked by udev rule

Tags: bash, udev

I am a Linux Mint user and I am trying to write a rule, that execute a script when I plug in the usb. The `#!/bin/sh script`, does not succeed 
to access the USB (even with a normal cd) while if I run the same 
script from command line, it works perfectly.

The rule I created for that purpose is:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="058f", ATTR{idProduct}=="6387", RUN+=="/home/dario/bin/backup_usb"
```

where the backup_usb for instance looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh
sleep 10
cd /media/dario/ 
echo " I am now in: $(pwd)" >> /home/dario/bin/log.log
cd /media/dario/DARIO_USB/  # That's the device just plugged in.
echo " I am now in: $(pwd)" >> /home/dario/bin/log.log
```

The output is:

```
I am now in: /media/dario/ 
and now in: /
```

while I was expecting:

```
I am now in: /media/dario/ 
and now in: /media/dario/DARIO_USB/
```

I would be very grateful for any help.

(This is the edited version of my question)

Comment: "Does not work" isn't enough for us to work from. At minimum, set up logging. Also, all the `=3D` stuff is broken -- each `=3D` is supposed to be a single `=` sign, and `=20` is similarly an escape code for a space.

Comment: Also, you're tagging your question bash, but using `#!/bin/sh` for POSIX sh. It can only be one or the other; which is it?

Comment: I guess I don't know how is it called. I am using #!/bin/sh. Is tag: shell the right Tag?

Comment: I am ignorant in scripting, so please enlighten me!

Comment: Yes, `shell` or `sh` is more appropriate than `bash` for `#!/bin/sh`. Or you could just use `#!/bin/bash` and keep the bash tag. :)

Comment: BTW, assuming that your udev rule triggered **when the device is plugged in** is happening not just after it's plugged in, but also after it's **mounted** isn't a valid assumption. The mount itself, after all, is triggered by udev.

Comment: Also, you want either `=` or `+=`, not `+==`, for the `RUN`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your rule is wrong. Consider something like:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="058f",
ATTR{idProduct}=="6387", RUN+="/home/dario/bin/backup_usb"
```

Second: Kill the `sleep 10`. If udev is running scripts in order and waiting for each to finish before running the next, it can potentially block any subsequent script (such as the one doing the mount), preventing it from happening at all. We're going to do this differently, putting the polling in the background:

```
#!/bin/bash
#      ^^^^ - has to be bash, as the C-style for loop syntax used below is a bashism
#             ...as is the [[ ]] construct.

exec </dev/null >/home/dario/usb.log 2>&1
set -x
cd /media/dario || exit
(
  for ((retries=0; retries<10; retries++)); do
    [[ -d DARIO_USB ]] && grep -q -e DARIO_USB /proc/mounts && continue
    sleep 1 # retry
  done
  cd DARIO_USB || exit
  echo "SUCCESS"
) &
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edit my question. I would have a question: What does      exec 2>/path/to/logfile; set -x; do?      Also the operations I am asking to do are trivial and perfectly working when invoking the same script from terminal

Comment: `exec 2>/path/to/logfile` redirects stderr from your script to a file named `/path/to/logfile`. `set -x` logs each command the script runs.

Comment: When you run from a terminal, your environment is going to be substantially different. Maybe you're depending on `PATH` elements that are present in your interactive shell but not in the shell invoked by udev -- whatever the cause is, the log should make it clear.

Comment: I am glad that your code worked. Thanks for the help. I accepted this answer because it was the most meaningful, but my main goal would be to understand my error, and unfortunately I still didn't. Thank you anyway for your help.

Comment: @dario, since this code (well, the parts in the `( ... ) &`) runs in the background, other udev scripts don't block waiting for it. That means that a separate trigger that actually mounts the USB device doesn't get stuck *behind* your script here that requires the device to be mounted before it'll work. Does that help?

Comment: @dario, ...I'm not sure that that was the only thing going on here, but I'd need a log of the stderr emitted by your other script running with `set -x` to make a certain diagnosis (consider, as the first line after the shebang, `exec 2>/tmp/mount.log; PS4=':$LINENO+'; set -x`). Without that content in the question, a succinct and certain explanation is not possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot. At this point I am satisfied. :) I have a lot of questions as I am not used to bash scripting but I guess that's not the right place! I wish you the best.

Comment: Would you know how to do the same thing with OS X? It should not be very different, this method you proposed me is working perfectly for Linux!!