# Executing a script after mounting USB key

Tags: bash, udev

I try to run a script to identify a USB key by checking its label, and also that it has a file containing an identifier. I was first inspired by this -> [Script not working when evoked by udev rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35045496/script-not-working-when-evoked-by-udev-rule)

Here is the udev rule first. It works properly and calls my script correctly.

```
KERNEL=="sd[b-z]1", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ACTION=="add", GROUP="plugdev", OWNER="tuxin", RUN+="/home/tuxin/insert-usbkey.sh %k"
```

Here is a script, reduced to its simplest expression, to test the operation.

```
#!/bin/bash
exec </dev/null >/tmp/key-inserted.log 2>&1; PS4=':$LINENO+'; set -x

KEY_LABEL="DEV_JP"

cd /media/tuxin || exit
(
  for ((retries=0; retries<10; retries++)); do
    [[ -d "$KEY_LABEL" ]] && grep -q -e "$KEY_LABEL" /proc/mounts && continue
    sleep 1
  done
  cd "$KEY_LABEL" || exit
  echo "SUCCESS"
) &
```

Unfortunately, despite the key being mounted, "SUCCESS" is never written in the log file, its content is:

```
:4+KEY_LABEL=DEV_JP
:6+cd /media/tuxin
:8+(( retries=0 ))
:8+(( retries<10 ))
:9+[[ -d DEV_JP ]]
:10+sleep 1
```

We can see that after the 'sleep' command, nothing else is executed. By doing several tests, I came to the conclusion that my script is stopped as soon as the key is mounted, and I can not do anything when the key is mounted.

So I continued my research and followed this discussion -> [how to execute a script every time any USB get mounted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208815/how-to-execute-a-script-every-time-any-usb-get-mounted)

So I put in place the following rule, which I have a little more trouble understanding, but the result is exactly the same:

```
KERNEL!="sd[a-z]*", GOTO="media_by_label_auto_mount_end" ACTION=="add", PROGRAM!="/sbin/blkid %N", GOTO="media_by_label_auto_mount_end"

# Get label
PROGRAM=="/sbin/blkid -o value -s LABEL %N", ENV{dir_name}="%c"

# use basename to correctly handle labels such as ../mnt/foo
PROGRAM=="/usr/bin/basename '%E{dir_name}'", ENV{dir_name}="%c" ENV{dir_name}=="", ENV{dir_name}="usbhd-%k"

ACTION=="add", ENV{dir_name}!="", RUN+="/bin/su tuxin -c '/usr/bin/pmount %N %E{dir_name}'", RUN+="/home/tuxin/insert-usbkey.sh"

ACTION=="remove", ENV{dir_name}!="", RUN+="/bin/su tuxin -c '/usr/bin/pumount /media/%E{dir_name}'"

LABEL="media_by_label_auto_mount_end"
```

The script works correctly when it is started manually, but executed by udev, as soon as the key is mounted, it seems to me that it is killed. How can I do what I want, work on the key after automatic detection of mounting ?

Here is a summary of the machines on which this script has been tested (with or without backgounded operations). It remains to understand why this does not work in Linux Mint.

```
  Distribution    udev version   Result
  -------------------------------------
  Linux Mint 18       229          KO
  L.M.D.E.            215          OK
  Poky custom.        182          OK
  Linux Mint 18       229          KO
  Lubuntu 18.04       237          OK
```

Comment: I couldn't tell you, but +1 for a well written question.

Comment: Weird. How about adding some traps to detect if it's being signaled, and redirect to `/tmp/key-inserted.log.$$` to ensure the file isn't being truncated by another instance

Comment: I put the udev logs in 'debug' mode: `udevadm control --log-priority=debug`, there is only one call to my script.

Answer (score 0):

Your test script runs its main logic in a *backgrounded subshell*. It therefore finishes almost immediately after launching the subshell, so the parent bash process dutifully signals all child processes, killing the subshell before it's able to do much.

Neither backgrounding nor subshelling is needed; the following works perfectly with udev on my system:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec </dev/null >/tmp/key-inserted.log 2>&1; PS4=':$LINENO+'; set -x

KEY_LABEL="DEV_JP"

cd /media/tuxin || exit

for ((retries=0; retries<10; retries++)); do
  [[ -d "$KEY_LABEL" ]] && grep -q -e "$KEY_LABEL" /proc/mounts && break
  sleep 1
done
cd "$KEY_LABEL" || exit
ls .  # Double-check by listing the drive's contents
echo "SUCCESS"
```

Also note that I changed your `continue` to `break` because that's exactly what you want to do when you've found what you're looking for: *break out of the loop*.

Comment: @Tuxin If this script doesn't see a mount point, but you _do_ see it after the script exits, it could be that your script's udev rule is running too early. Name your rule file with something like `99-zzz-usbkey.rules` to ensure that it'll run after all the system USB-mount-related rules. As the [udev(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/udev.7.html) man page says: "All rules files are collectively sorted and processed **in lexical order, regardless of the directories in which they live**."

Comment: No Adrian, I have already tested several names of rules, including 99, it does not change anything. And when the script does not see a mount point, there really is not! When the mount point exists, the script has been stopped before seeing it.

Comment: Then something weird is going on. Please post on pastebin.com (or some other pastebin site) the **full** udev debug logs, showing exactly what happens when you insert a USB drive.

Comment: [Here](https://pastebin.com/i0r3Vfec) are the logs when the key is mounted and the script is stopped (_backgrounded subshell_). And [these](https://pastebin.com/ixZzYRM1), when the key does not mount and the script goes to the end.

Comment: Well, I'm stumped. I can confirm that the foreground script I posted runs perfectly on Lubuntu 18.04 with system-udev v237, and doesn't block udisksd auto-mounting. You could try a different distro, in case there was a regression between v215 and v237.